# What is/was a court of "judicature," and how is it named?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, court

Supreme court of judicature etc. I feel like it may even still be a thing in Scotland, but you see it in older EWCA decisions. What does the word mean and what does it note to qualify a court's name with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that is simply another term for a "court of law" or for a "court of justice". All of those terms simply mean a court, a place where judgements under law are made. Which term is used is a matter of history and tradition, or perhaps of style.

The term does not of itself imply any difference of rules or authority or procedure. Different courts do have different procedures to some extent, and if one court normally uses one term for itself, then that term may go with that court's procedure to some extent.

- [Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/judicature) gives as sense 2:

> a court of justice

- [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/judicature)  gives as sense 4:

> a court of law

- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/judicature) gives:

> the legal system and the work it does

- The [legal section](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/judicature) of the *Free Dictionary* gives:

> A term used to describe the judicial branch of government; the judiciary; or those connected with the court system. ... Judicature refers to those officers who administer justice and keep the peace. It signifies a tribunal or court of justice. ... [sense 5] a court of justice or such courts collectively.